# How to achieve orchestration with spring boot micro service?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, orchestration

what is best way to orchestrate micro services in spring boot.

Comment: what exactly you mean by orchestration. elaborate

Comment: I mean http orchestration, i have multiple micro services. At client(angular) i need data from one or more services in a single HTTP call. There may be cases where one service request may depend on another like call to service.

Answer (score 4):

You have many options but I will list 3 of them that I would choose from:

1. Directly call the other microservice using REST calls (hard code the URL in a property file or create a service for inter service communication).
2. Setup microservice architecture with [spring-cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) and [netflix OSS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/)
3. Setup microservice architecture with [spring-cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) and [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)

Comment: I already set up my architecture with spring-cloud and Netflix OSS , With this comb how can i achieve  my requirements. I tried [conductor](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/) but have setup issues.

Comment: As an easy approach, use eureka to get a microservice by name (application-name) and query it in another microservice logic layer.

Comment: i am doing it right now it work fine, i use feign for service to service calls.But i have situation where i have to use it frequently which increase the code complexity. my doubt is whether orchestration is required for this process.

Comment: It is very opinion-based and use-case related, there is no good or bad answer for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback.